# I don't remember me having a problem at home. what does this imply?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Here's the sentence that I get mixed up.

> Q: Tell me about a problem you had at home.
>
> A: I don't remember me having a problem at home.

I'd like to know what it implies.

> a. I had a problem at home, but I don't remember in detail.
>
> b. I'm not sure if I had a problem at home. I'm pretty sure that I didn't have a problem at home.
>
> c. I haven't had a problem at home ever

Comment: Note, by the way, that when the subject of the main clause and the gerund clause are the same, it's usually omitted from the gerund clause: "I don't remember having a problem at home". It would only be repeated for contrast: "I don't remember **me** having a problem, it was usually my brother."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is described best by b, however if it was said sarcastically/if the person was challenging the other person it would be described by c.